# Will two Type IIS restriction sites cut if they are directly back-to-back?

Tags: restriction-enzymes

I want to put two BbsI (or BsaI) restriction sites right next to each other, facing out, like this:

```
       \/ |BbsI||BbsI|  \/
CTCAAATGCGGTCTTCGAAGACGTTTTAGAG
   /\                      /\
```

Should I expect this to cut, or are the two restriction enzymes going to block each other?